# Flutter function returning at await statement

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, couchdb

I am using flutter with the cbl package to persist data. Trying to retrieve the entries does not seem to work because the function created is returning at the await statement and not the return statement. This does not seem like the intended result of darts async/await functionality. So I am lost.

task_database.dart

```
  Future<dynamic> getAllTasks() async {
    final tasksDb = await Database.openAsync(database);  <---------- Returns here 

    var tasksQuery = const QueryBuilder()
        .select(SelectResult.all())
        .from(DataSource.database(tasksDb));
    final resultSet = await tasksQuery.execute();

    late var task;
    
    await for (final result in resultSet.asStream()) {
      final map = result.toPlainMap();
      final taskDao = TaskDao.fromJson(map);
      task = taskDao.task;
      // Do something with the task...
      print(task);
    }
    ;

    return task; <-------------------------------------------- Does not make it here
  }
```

task_cubit.dart

```
    getAllTasks() => {
        allTaskMap = TasksAbcDatabase().getAllTasks(),
        emit(TaskState(tasks: state. Tasks))
    };
```

What I have tried. I have tried to use Database.openSync instead of Database.openAsync however, the function just returns at the next await statement. I have also tried making getAllTasks asynchronous and awaiting the database as such.

```
    Future<void> getAllTasks() async => {
        allTaskMap = await TasksAbcDatabase().getAllTasks(),
        emit(TaskState(tasks: state. Tasks))
    };
```

However this has the same issue, when the function from task_database returns prematurely it  the returns at the first await function in getAllTasks which is the allTaskMap variable.

Thanks

Comment: Your `getAllTasks` implementations create and return `Set` literals.  Is that what you intend?  Both versions return `Set`s of two elements, and nothing enforces that the second element (the result of `emit(...)`) is evaluated after `getAllTasks()` completes.  I suspect that you intend for the `{` and `}` to denote a *function body*, not a `Set` literal, in which case you shouldn't be using `=>`. (`Result f() => y;` is shorthand for `Result f() { return y; }`.)

Comment: Interesting. I just took a look at the dart language tour and sets. And I am unsure how () => {} creates a set. However i did notice that the linter when creating a variable with the mentioned format recommends me to place curly braces? Is that why.

Comment: The Dart Language Tour explains that `=> expr` is shorthand for `{ return expr; }` and that the expression `{'fluorine', 'chlorine', 'bromine', 'iodine', 'astatine'}` is a `Set` literal.  Putting them together,`() => {}` therefore is equivalent to `() { return {}; }` which returns a `Set`.  Note that this is different from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

A function *cannot* "return prematurely" without a `return` statement.

The only way the execution is cut short would be an `exception` being `throw`n.

I also don't see how you don't get syntax errors, when you don't `await` the `Database.openAsync(database)` statement.

So make sure all your `await`s are in place. Use the linter to find those that are missing. While you are at it, remove the keyword `dynamic` from your vocabulary, it will only hurt you if you use it without a need for it. Your return type should be properly typed, then your compiler could tell you, that returning a single task from a function that is clearly supposed to return multiple tasks is not going to work.

Either catch your exceptions and make sure you know there was one, or do not catch them and watch them go all the way through into your debugger.

In addition, following the comment of @jamesdlin, your function definitions are... valid, but probably not doing what you think they are doing.

```
Future<void> getAllTasks() async => {
    allTaskMap = await TasksAbcDatabase().getAllTasks(),
    emit(TaskState(tasks: state. Tasks))
};
```

needs to be

```
Future<void> getAllTasks() async {
    allTaskMap = await TasksAbcDatabase().getAllTasks();
    emit(TaskState(tasks: state. Tasks));
}
```

Comment: Apologies I changed the code back and forgot to add the await keyword. I've updated the code. Also the linter does not show any issues with the code. But the thing is the code works with the when using the synchronous version to open the database. I also tried wrapping the Database opening in a try catch block however the same issue persist. The debugger reaches just before the await keyword and the returns out of the function.